# Time based video search engine

Tags: search, video-player

I have a collection of demonstration videos and I would like to be able to store what happens in the videos so I can view snippets from them later on. each video might contain multiple patterns made up of different moves so I want to be able to  view a whole pattern as well as individual moves.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What OS shall the software run on, what features do you need, what is your price limit when it comes to paid solutions.