# Video clip viewer

Tags: video, file-search

I have a collection of video files stored on my windows 10 pc. Instead of splitting or reediting the videos I would like an application where I can

- View a video and bookmark clips within it.
- Search for related clips
- Ideally it would be free software

### Use case

The videos are from demonstrations after a dance class. Since different clips might use the same move It would be great to view those clips together. As I would be able to see different options.

this is an expanded version of the question [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/44954/time-based-video-search-engine).